# Cross-domain reactjs component

Tags: reactjs, react

Lets say I have some react components on domain-a.com.

From domain-b.com, an applications calls an API endpoint on domain-a.com. This end point returns the .js of the above mentioned react components (bundled). These are then executed on domain-b.com. The react components render a UI and call some end points on domain-a.com.

Is there any CORS issues with domain-b.com running those components on its own domain. 
I am basically trying to create cross-domain react components and trying to figure out what is the easiest way to go about this without hitting security issues.

Comment: ReactJs is just JavaScript.  Look for problems regarding CORS and Javascript and you have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, CORS is bound to occur if you are requesting for resources from another origin due to security concerns.
   Good article to understand - http://restlet.com/company/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/
2. other way you can call your backend and let him handle all the heavy lifting. 
   [image]